# JSONDecoder parsing incoherence

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I went across a problem when decoding a JSON file.

The file structure is as follows:

```
{"grocery":
    [
        { "vegetables":
            {"quantity":"some",
            "compostable":true,
            "stockageSite":"string",
            "package":"bag"
            },

        "meats":
            {"quantity":"string",
            "compostable":true,
            "stockageSite":"string",
            "package":"box"
            },

        "site":"string",
        "active":true,
        "name":"string"
        }
    ]
}
```

for which I have the following structs

```
struct Goods: Codable {
    
    var quantity: String
    var compostable: Bool
    var stockageSite: String
    var package: String
}

struct Details: Codable {
    
    var vegetables: Goods
    var meats: Goods
    var site: String
    var active: Bool
    var name: String
}

struct Grocery: Codable {

    var grocery: [Details]
}
```

the decoding (do-catch with

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place: \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if response.statusCode != 200{
                    print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
                }
            }
            if let data = data{
              
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 do {
            let jsonParse: Grocery =  try decoder.decode(Grocery.self, from: data)
            print("parsed \(jsonParse)")
}
catch let jsonError as NSError{
                    
                    print("Failed \(jsonError)")
                }
```

) parses very well with no errors throwed as long as I remove the "quantity" or "stockage site" or "package" from Goods (-> i.e, the ones with string values, exactly as if more than 2 string items doesn't work there). Otherwise, there's no parsing and the code execution stops there. No error throwed (except in Playgrounds:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

The string type is the good one, there are no typos. The "compostable" (bool) is well recognized.

(The same thing happens if I add a string element to "Details" and change my json accordingly.)

here are the results printed after correct parsing (whichever of the 3 string elements is removed, so "package" can be parsed correctly):

parsed Grocery(grocery: [__lldb_expr_5.Details(vegetables: __lldb_expr_5.Goods(quantity: "some", compostable: true, stockageSite: "string"), meats: __lldb_expr_5.Goods(quantity: "string", compostable: true, stockageSite: "string"), site: "string", active: true, name: "string")])

and (sometimes! but why?!) the error message printed :

Failed Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(__lldb_expr_7.Details, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "grocery", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected Details but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

just as if the third string element was never found. Would you have a hint of what is going on?

Comment: Do you create error variable and print it ?

do {
// ...
} catch (let error) { 
print(error)
}

Comment: "parses very well with no errors throwed"  How?  Where does a guy named 'data' come from?

Comment: Declare them as optional

Comment: Edited my question for the comments above. Optional won't change anything. Printing the data as a string shows the values are there.

Comment: @NightCoder show your actual JSON. Nobody will be able to help if you post your JSON which doesn't make any sense. At least add the error you said you are catching.

Comment: I think the issue is that some items are missing those keys.

Comment: You should provide an example JSON that you actually want to be able to parse. Such things as `bool` are distracting.

Comment: Updated with the actual json used for my playgrounds - for me it makes sense ;), and with the error that sometimes happens, sometimes not. The json is local, so the keys are always present.

Comment: In fact, this is maybe on Xcode's side, as I test other JSON files: two nested structures of min.4 items + 2 elements is too much. Two nested structures with 3 items with more than 3 elements is also too much. I catched an error, that can appear is I add too much items:   Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ valueNotFound : 2 elements
    - .0 : __lldb_expr_72.Details
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "The given data did not contain a top-level value."
      - underlyingError : nil

Comment: seems related to a known problem here that was reported as corrected but apparently is not: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665159

Answer (score 0):

The Question needs more information but I will guess that the keys in those objects sometimes are missing so here is how you can handle that, by simply using `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and giving default values for missing keys using `decodeIfPresent` change your `Goods` struct to this

```
    struct Goods: Codable {
    var quantity: String
    var compostable: String
    var stockageSite: String
    
   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case quantity
        case compostable
        case stockageSite
   }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        self.quantity = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .quantity) ?? "Empty"
        self.compostable = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .compostable) ?? "Empty"
        self.stockageSite = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .stockageSite) ?? "Empty"

        }
}
```

Comment: thank you! But the JSON is a local file, the keys are not missing

Comment: have you gave it a try ? the answer

Comment: and make those 2 keys optional

Comment: I did … unfortunately no changes :(